# Finding more maximum & minimum elements in a list of lists

Tags: python

`[[209, 34], [50, 170], [197, 76], [75, 156], [176, 51], [54, 141], [205, 19], [35, 173]]`

I asked a similar question which was answered, and this is different.

How do I find the two sublists which sum is maximised and have the maximum values for element 0 and for element 1

So in the list above, I would get back `[209,34]` because it's sum is `243` and `209` is the largest element for element 0 in all pairs, and I would also get back `[75,156]` because it's sum is `231` (the third largest sum) and 156 is the largest value for element 1 (but I wouldn't get back `197,76` because neither element is maximised, even though it has a larger overall value)

Comment: 156 is not the largest value for element 1. The largest is 173.

Comment: not sure about the question. `max(a, key=lambda d: [sum(d), d[0]])`. Hope it works

Comment: yes, but the sum is not the larger of the two. 156 + 75 > 35 + 173

Comment: I don't understand the conditions. Is it all the pairs where either the first or the second is the biggest number of the list? Then, `max(a, key=lambda d: d[0])` for the first, and `d[1]` for the second. How does the sum play any role here?

Comment: if I understand the question right this should help. `a[np.argmax(a,0)]` . Note `a=np.array(a)`